# Windows Forms C# Pot To Mac OS X (easiest way)

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, operating-system, cross-platform

Been searching the web and stackoverflow for 3 days, and I can't find an answer for what I need. I am a C# developer, not a Pro one but I am pretty good with developing Windows (desktop) software.

Now I want to port a windows software to Mac, but I simply can't find a guide on how to do this.

I installed VS coomunity 2015 with xamarin, but I didn't find any tutorials or guide on how to port a desktop software to mac os X (not to ios/windows phone).

I know that using Mono will help do that, but I simply have no clue where to start. I installed vmware with elcapitan, have everything set-up but I have no clue what to do next.

So knowing that I developed a C# .net app, that uses only the default .net libs that are supported in MONO, what should I do to port it on mac os X?

How can I compile in VS 2015 and simply run on Mac OS X?

Thanks a lot!
 Vlad

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/

Comment: i read that page already, but still, it's about xamarain studio, right? i want to work with visual studio, and with windows forms.

Answer (score 0):

Developing a Xamarin.Mac app is currently not supported in Visual Studio and requires Xamarin Studio running on a Mac with the latest version of Xcode installed.

Windows Forms and Windows APIs are **not** supported in Xamarin.Mac so you will need to port your UI to `NSWindows`, `NSViewControllers` and `NSViews`. However, you can share the back end code across platforms such as your data models and business level classes. A typical app can share up to 80% of the code across platform.

I would suggest starting with our [Hello, Mac](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/getting_started/hello,_mac/) documentation as it gives a needed base required for the rest of the Mac documentation.